# How to change my regex to match more than one promise syntax?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regex that match syntax of promise code.

The regex also matches inside the promise syntax (by name of the group: a,b,c and d).

So using the regex I know what is inside the callbacks and what are the args.

```
then\([\n\s]+function\s*\((?<a>.*)\)\s*\{[\n\s]+(?<b>[\s\S]+)\},[\n\s]*function\s*\((?<c>.*)\)\s*\{[\n\s]*(?<d>[\s\S]+)?\}[\n\s]*\);
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EE2QxT/3)

This is works fine when I have only one promise syntax:
[image]

But not so match when I have more than one promise phrases:
[image]

Is there a way to make a groups of each phrases and still have the inner groups?

In Javascript code is the most matters.

In the console I log the `b` which have the match of everything after the `then`.

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-robinson-hhx9r?file=/src/index.js:0-466)

```
console.clear();

const code = `
promise().then(
  function (result) {
    ...
  },
  function (err) { ... }
);

..............................

promise().then(
  function (result) {
    ...
  },
  function (err) { ... }
);
`;

const p = new RegExp(/then\([\n\s]+function\s*\((?<a>.*)\)\s*\{[\n\s]+(?<b>[\s\S]+)\},[\n\s]*function\s*\((?<c>.*)\)\s*\{[\n\s]*(?<d>[\s\S]+)?\}[\n\s]*\);/gmi);

code.replace(p, (x, a,b,c,d) => {

  console.log({ x, a, b, c });
});
```

Comment: Your sample is using PCRE, or do you execute this in JavaScript?

Comment: I get the same result by running this regex though Javascript code, and for the demo I write it in regex101. so I think if it work in regex101 it work also in my code.

Comment: Well, there are features like recursion that will work in PCRE but not in JavaScript, that's why I ask.

Comment: I edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, this is an unpleasant task to do when using JavaScript's regex since we miss out on features like recursion and others that would come in handy; I tried to do this in one go ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/p9Z1U9/1)) but in the end, I think it is better to match the then(...); part first and then dissect the inner part; e.g. like this:

```js
const regex = /(then\()(?:(?!\1|\\).)*?\);/gs;
const rxInner = /(?:function\s*\((?<a>.*?)\)\s*\{\s+(?<b>[\s\S]+?)\},\s*function\s*\((?<c>.*?)\))/gs;
const str = `    promise().then(
      function (result1) {
        ...
      },
      function (err) { ... }
    );
   
   ..............................

promise().then(
      function (result2) {
        ...
      },
      function (err) { ... }
    );`;
let match = regex.exec(str);
do {
  console.log(match);
  let m = rxInner.exec(match[0]);
  do {
    console.log(`  a:${m.groups.a} 
  b:${m.groups.b}
  c:${m.groups.c}`); 
  } while((m = rxInner.exec(match[0])) !== null);
  
} while((match = regex.exec(str)) !== null);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/xregexp/xregexp-all.js"></script>
```